# Which Spring & Hibernate Version to be used

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, rest

I am new to `Spring` & `Hibernate`. I have to develop some `REST API`. So i need help to choose correct version of `Spring` & `Hibernate`. Some beginner developer suggest `spring 3.0` & `Hibernat2 2.0`. Does it a right choice or i have to go with `spring 3.0` and `spring 3.0`?

Comment: I generally read each corresponding manual and use latest stable version. If I find problem then check the release notes, try previous stable

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No. Not at all. These two versions are completely obsolete. Use Spring's latest stable version (4.0.5 at the moment, as clearly indicated on the [home page](http://projects.spring.io/spring-framework)), and Hibernate's latest stable version (4.3.5.Final at the moment, as clearly indicated on the [home page](http://hibernate.org/orm)).

New versions of frameworks are released to fix bugs in previous versions, and provide more, better features. Why would you stick with old, unsupported versions instead of using the latest ones?

Comment: Sometimes you are stuck with a particular jdk and latest version requires a higher jdk.

Answer (score 1):

We have an application for banking domain due to go live soon built on

- JDK 7
- Spring 4.0.2.RELEASE
- Hibernate 4.3.3.Final

This is almost the newest versions of respective libraries.
We do have the liberty of upgrading to latest and greatest version for the core framework on top of which this application is built and it has always worked great. If you have to decide the version always go for the latest.

Answer (score 0):

Just to share with you, our project has been working fine with the following combinations:

- JDK 1.6
- Spring Framework 3.0.5.RELEASE
- Hibernate 3.6.1